# How to dump methods of structs in Golang?

Tags: go

The Golang "*fmt*" package has a dump method called `Printf("%+v", anyStruct)`. I'm looking for any method to dump a struct *and its methods too*.

For example:

```
type Foo struct {
    Prop string
}
func (f Foo)Bar() string {
    return f.Prop
}
```

I want to check the existence of the `Bar()` method in an initialized instance of type `Foo` (not only properties).

Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can list the methods of a type using the `reflect` package.  For example:

```
fooType := reflect.TypeOf(&Foo{})
for i := 0; i < fooType.NumMethod(); i++ {
    method := fooType.Method(i)
    fmt.Println(method.Name)
}
```

You can play around with this here: http://play.golang.org/p/wNuwVJM6vr

With that in mind, if you want to check whether a type implements a certain method set, you might find it easier to use interfaces and a type assertion.  For instance:

```
func implementsBar(v interface{}) bool {
    type Barer interface {
        Bar() string
    }
    _, ok := v.(Barer)
    return ok
}

...
fmt.Println("Foo implements the Bar method:", implementsBar(Foo{}))
```

Or if you just want what amounts to a compile time assertion that a particular type has the methods, you could simply include the following somewhere:

```
var _ Barer = Foo{}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I didn't want to use "reflect" package, so your suggestion using interface looks so cool for me!

Comment: To find the *T methods you have to provide a `TypeOf(&Foo{})`

Comment: Thanks James and @BGAdrian, would you pls help how can I get the method interface as well?

Comment: @Davood [how to list method names in an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071659/how-to-list-out-the-method-name-in-an-interface-type) and [how to determine a method set in an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798594/how-to-determine-the-method-set-of-an-interface-in-golang) use reflect to do this.