# Is it possible to get the function name with reflect like this?

Tags: go

Is it possible to get the function name with reflect like this?

I am a new **golang** programmer,I don't know how to solve it.

The code following:

```
type A struct {
    Name string
}

func (this *A) Func1(name string) {
    fmt.Println(name)
}

func (this *A) Func2(name string, value string) {
    fmt.Println(name + ": " + value)
}

func main() {
    a := new(A)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a)

    for i := 0; i < v.NumMethod(); i++ {
        method := v.Method(i)
        if method.IsValid() {
            t := reflect.TypeOf(method.Interface())
            // how to echo the function name of A: Func1,Func2
            fmt.Printf("%s  %d  %d\n", runtime.FuncForPC(method.Pointer()).Name(), t.NumIn(), t.NumOut())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer, might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397653/how-to-dump-methods-of-structs-in-golang

Answer (score -1):

Thanks machiel.

The answer following:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(new(A))
for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
    method := t.Method(i)
    fmt.Println(method.Name)
}
```