# How to determine the method set of an interface in Golang?

Tags: go, interface

How would one print the method set of the following interface?

```
type Searcher interface {
    Search(query string) (found bool, err error)
    ListSearches() []string
    ClearSearches() (err error)
}
```

Such that

```
Search
ListSearches
ClearSearches
```

is printed out? (Without knowledge of a concrete type which implements it).

Comment: Question was, how print methods. Therefore the simples solution is: **godoc . Searcher** (replace . with name of package, if you want to ask to not current package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using reflection:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(new(Searcher)).Elem()
fmt.Println(t)

for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
    fmt.Println(t.Method(i).Name)
}
```

Prints:

```
main.Searcher
ClearSearches
ListSearches
Search
```

Answer (score 2):

`reflect` package is the right tool for this.Using reflection one can get the type information of a variable without knowing the type before hand . Here is a code snippet showing how to get the function names of functions defined as needed by an interface

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Searcher interface {
    Search(query string) (found bool, err error)
    ListSearches() []string
    ClearSearches() (err error)
}

func main() {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(struct{ Searcher }{})
    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(t.Method(i).Name)
    }
}
```

Check the [golangplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/vzPXxMgOql)