# How to list out the method name in an interface type?

Tags: go, reflection

For example,

```
type FooService interface {
    Foo1(x int) int
    Foo2(x string) string
}
```

What I am attempting to do is getting list `["Foo1", "Foo2"]` using runtime reflection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the method set of an interface in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798594/how-to-determine-the-method-set-of-an-interface-in-golang)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf((*FooService)(nil)).Elem()
var s []string
for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
    s = append(s, t.Method(i).Name)
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/-AHYGJnxvb)

Getting the reflect.Type for the interface type is the tricky part. See [How to get the reflect.Type of an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132848/how-to-get-the-reflect-type-of-an-interface) for an explanation.

Comment: `t := reflect.TypeOf(struct{FooService}{})` also works.

Comment: `reflect.TypeOf(struct{FooService}{})` works for listing the methods, but it does not work for accessing other information about the interface type.