# Convert String to Function name in GO?

Tags: go

I am creating a Restful API.

I am passing function name and arguments in JSON

eg. `"localhost/json_server?method=foo&id=1"`

Lets say, i have a simple go server running

```
 http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {                                                                             
     fmt.Println("path",r.URL.Path )                                                                                                             
     fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))                                                                                  
 }) 
.........
function json_server(){
....
}
```

The `r.url.Path` will give me "*`json_server`*" in **string**. Now i want to first check if the function exists , if exists call the function as defined else throw some exception.

Is this possible to do ?

When i am doing **python** and  i use `getattr(method,args)` to call the method and arguments which are in string.

I have developed interest in Go after using Docker. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to enumerate the functions of a package using the [reflection api](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), but see [this mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/9Di5eHK2eQ0) for some ideas involving parsing the source files. Enumerating methods of an object [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397653/how-to-dump-methods-of-structs-in-golang), which is actually more to what you describe in python.

However, I would recommend using a simple dispatch table instead of introspection, you can populate a `map[string]func()`, though I suspect you might want to pass some arguments to your function, e.g. the request to be handled:

```
var dispatch map[string]http.HandlerFunc

func init() {
    dispatch = make(map[string]http.HandlerFunc)
    dispatch["json_server"] = json_server
    dispatch["foo"] = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ...
    }
}

func ServeHTTP (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if handler, exists := dispatch[req.URL.Path]; exists {
        handler(w, r)
    } else {
        ... // fallback
    }
}
```

Or better yet, just use an existing HTTP router, such as [httprouter](https://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) or [gorilla/mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux). There are many alternatives to choose from.