# Is there a way to list methods of an object in GoLang?

Tags: object, go

I want to know if Golang offers a built-in function to list methods of a particular object? Something like dir() in python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) -- Are you looking for documentation, or runtime reflection?

Comment: You can use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397653/how-to-dump-methods-of-structs-in-golang) at run time, or if it's for your own analysis, [Go Guru](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_Y9xCEMj5S-7rv2ooHpZNH15JgRT5iM742gJkw5LtmQ/edit) is an option